# How can I customize the Validator for Hibernate Validator's method validation with Seam?

Tags: seam, hibernate-validator

I'm using Hibernate Validator and added some custom validation annotations, resource bundle location and a custom message interpolator. This is all done by customizing the Validator at bootstrapping time.

Now I'm trying to validate methods, but of course I don't get my nicely configured Validator, since the standard Validator is injected for `@AutoValidating`.

How can I customize the Validator within Seam Validation?

---

Here's how I create the Validator:

```
public static javax.validation.Validator getBeanValidator(final Locale locale,
    final ResourceBundle... resourceBundles) {
  HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure();
  FallbackResourceBundleLocator resourceBundleLocator = new FallbackResourceBundleLocator(
      configuration.getDefaultResourceBundleLocator(), resourceBundles);
  configuration.messageInterpolator(new FieldMessageInterpolator(locale, resourceBundleLocator));
  javax.validation.ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = configuration.buildValidatorFactory();
  return validatorFactory.getValidator();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to configure the default validator using [META-INF/validation.xml](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e2218), which is the validator used by Seam Validation.

Alternatively you could create your own interceptor based on [the one](https://github.com/seam/validation/blob/develop/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/seam/validation/ValidationInterceptor.java) from Seam Validation, and use your custom configured `Validator` there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I think the first would be the best, but I don't see all options which I need, since I have my own resource bundle locator, see above.

Comment: Ok, I see. In this case I think you have to write your own interceptor.